# SQL SERVER table alias in stored proc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to give an alias to a table which will then be referenced within a store procedure.

```
Declare @target= (sometalbewithveryverylonganduglyname)
Declare @source= (anothertablewithaveryuglyverylongverybadname)

Select * from @target

Insert into @target select from @source

delete from @source
```

Reason being, the table source and target could change (if the tablename is changed then we just change in one location), and for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can't do:

```
Select * from @target
```

unless `@target` is defined as a table-variable, which requires you to set up the table as a user-defined type first.  If you're attempting to assign the name of a physical table to the variable and access it this way you'd need to execute the statement using dynamic SQL.

```
exec ('Select * from @target')
```

If you just want to alias the table you could write your query like this:

```
Select * from sometalbewithveryverylonganduglyname AS t
```

From your question, sounds like the table name can change so you're going to need to use dynamic SQL in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you describe unless you resort to dynamic SQL as Yuck suggested, but doing that for the sake of not writing a long table name is not a valid justification. SSMS already includes intellisense and for SQL Server 2005 and below, you can use one of many of the [free tools out there](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/). That should reduce the amount of typing that you need to do as well as misspelling mistakes.

Besides, you can always do `select t.column1 from really_long_and_ugly_name t ...`

Answer (score 0):

option 1) In that case you don't want to use a stored procedure, use some ORM library, it will allow you to switch between different table names with the same structure very easy

option 2) use views, that's what they are for, to hide underlying tables and allow those types of changes